# Are distorted graphics caused by AndEngine/GL + Android Nougat, or a bug in the AVD?

Tags: android-studio, opengl-es, andengine, android-virtual-device

I'm getting some buggy graphics behaviour when I run my AndEngine-based app on AVDs with the Android 7.0 (Nougat) image in Android Studio 2.2.2. The result is normal [when I use Android 6 (link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJdud.png), but it is translated, enlarged and wrapped in the x-dimension, with distorted colours [when I use Android 7 (link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjGxy.png).

Has anyone had experience with this type of graphics distortion? Could it be caused by Android 7.0 not being backward-compatible with something in AndEngine/OpenGL, or a problem with the Nougat image in Android Studio's AVD?

The minimal app I used to recreate the behaviour uses AndEngine (GLES2-AnchorCenter) to display a sprite on the main scene. I've tested it with several AVDs and it is consistently buggy with Nougat regardless of the device.

```
public class MainActivity extends SimpleLayoutGameActivity {
    private static int CAMERA_WIDTH = 480;
    private static int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 800;
    private Scene mScene;
    private ITextureRegion myTexture;

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutID() {
        return R.layout.activity_main;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getRenderSurfaceViewID() {
        return R.id.gameview;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle pSavedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(pSavedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine(EngineOptions pEngineOptions) {
        return new Engine(pEngineOptions);
    }

    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        ScreenOrientation orientation = ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_FIXED;
        EngineOptions en = new EngineOptions(true, orientation,
                new FillResolutionPolicy(), new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT));
        return en;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onPauseGame() {
        super.onPauseGame();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onResumeGame() {
        super.onResumeGame();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreateResources() {

        BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");

        final BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas gameTextureAtlasBIPMA2  = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(),
                136, 136, BitmapTextureFormat.RGBA_4444, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
        myTexture = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(
                gameTextureAtlasBIPMA2, this.getAssets(), "redbomb.png");
        try {
            gameTextureAtlasBIPMA2.build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(2, 0, 2));
            gameTextureAtlasBIPMA2.load();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error loading BIPMA2", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Scene onCreateScene() {
        this.mScene = new Scene();

        // Add a sprite
        float diameter = CAMERA_WIDTH/1.5f;
        this.mScene.attachChild(new Sprite(CAMERA_WIDTH/2f, CAMERA_HEIGHT/2f,
                diameter, myTexture.getHeight() * diameter / myTexture.getWidth(),
                myTexture, getVertexBufferObjectManager()));

        return this.mScene;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I have isolated the cause to the use of RGBA_4444 as the texture pixel format; when changed to RGBA_8888 the graphics are normal. Still, if anyone knows how to fix it so that I can use RGBA_4444...

Comment: I have no idea what would cause that rendering issue. It looks a bit similar to issues when I had resolution with 16 bit color but part of graphics driver decided to read it like 32 bit buffer. But there is huge difference so not exactly that problem. You can try debug issue with gltracer/debugger (for example: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/gltracer.html). If you compare GL trace you might be able to notice where the bug is. It is also good idea to check if different Android devices have same GL driver. A lot of devices share same GPU design. (driver bug is possible)

Comment: Thanks Pauli. It looks like Studio's GL tracer doesn't work on virtual devices, only real devices. I found the problem though, and you were really close, it was how many bits for the RGBA.

Comment: Virtual devices forwards GL commands to your desktop driver. You could try use a GL tracer for whole virtual device. Too bad that will include minor extra noise from surfaceflinger. It should provide descent enough trace to see what texture upload settings android gets wrong when forwarding GL calls to your desktop. It can be texture format or GL_UNPACK setting error.